# In Second Species Composition, how do you traverse an octave between downbeats

Tags: theory, counterpoint

From what I understand you can have an octave leap from one downbeat to the next in first species as long as it rebounds with a step in the opposite direction.

However, in programming second species, I can find no rule on what acceptable half notes I can have:

An escape tone (2nd-7th) would cause a leap of a 7th which is note allowed...

A change of register (Up a 9th, down a 2nd) would require a leap of greater than an octave which  isn't allowed.

I don't see anything about leaps of a 6th and 3rd or a 5th and a 4th. Are those allowed?

Or are octave leaps between downbeats just not allowed in second species?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean second-species counterpoint in the 16th-century Renaissance style, the rule is generally (and here I quote from Harold Owen's *Modal and Tonal Counterpoint*, p. 30):

> Two or more consecutive leaps in one direction are rare. When they do occur, they outline a consonant harmony, usually a major or minor triad.

Furthermore, note that leaps of sixths in this style are almost exclusively *minor* sixths. This means that the only possible way of traversing an octave would be by M3/m6, P4/P5, or P5/P4. As such, consecutive octave downbeats created by consecutive leaps would be very rare.

However, Owen says that:

> In sacred music of this period a single pitch  may be used as many as three times in succession.

Thus it might be possible to leap an octave *within the course of a single measure* and then repeat that upper pitch on the downbeat of the next measure before proceeding by step in the opposite direction. This would create consecutive octave downbeats, but not as a result of consecutive leaps.